# Oracle with Entity Frameworks throws “System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.”

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Working with EF6 and Oracle for the first time, trying to run a test which has produced the following error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException: Can not load Oracle client. Check your PATH environment variable and registry settings.
```

I've checked the PATH environment variable, and it's pointing to the right place, but not sure what to start with as far as the registry settings goes.  Hoping someone can give me some pointers on this.

Comment: What's your connection string look like? Also, check your tnsnames.ora or use a connection string with those settings. https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/

Comment: I figured it out, there were several factors at play.  What seems to have fixed it is installing the 32 bit client as well as the 64 bit client.  I guess this is a known issue, has been for a while.